# How do I write a time derivative with a ‘square math accent’?

Tags: symbols

I need to write this time derivative with a ‘square math accent’. Can anybody help me? I have found `\dot`, `\hat`, `\tilde`, `\breve`, but not this square!

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: `\square` with `\usepackage{amssymb}` should be what you are looking for: `\overset{\square}{y} = \dot{y} + Fv`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Peter! It worked just exactly the way I needed!

Comment: @PeterGrill Would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\overset` (`amsmath`) or `\accentset` (`accents`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents} % for accentset

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\accentset{\square}{y} = \dot{y} + Fv \\
\overset{\square}{y} = \dot{y} + Fv \\
\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\square}{y} = \dot{y} + Fv \\
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

In any case, you should define a macro for this: one among

```
\newcommand{\sqder}[1]{\accentset{\square}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sqder}[1]{\overset{\square}{#1}}
\newcommand{\sqder}[1]{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\square}{#1}}
```

and the formula above will be typeset

```
\sqder{y} = \dot{y} + Fv
```

This way you can always change your mind about how to implement the decoration.

[image]